# OR query matching nil or "" with Mongoid still matches ""?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to write a query for an embedded Mongoid::Document which finds any record where the "address" field is neither nil nor "".

Using a combination of the MongoDB documentation, [this issue in the Mongoid bug reports](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/914), and the Mongoid documentation, I think that something like this should work:

```
scope :with_address, where("$or" => [{:address => {"$ne" => nil}}, {:address => {"$ne" => ""}}])
```

When I run this, the selector looks ok:

```
1.9.2p290 :002 > report.document.records.with_address
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"$or"=>[{:address=>{"$ne"=>nil}}, {:address=>{"$ne"=>""}}]},  
  options:  {},
  class:    GlobalBoarding::MerchantPrincipal,
  embedded: true>
```

But when I look at the results, they contain an entry with a blank address:

```
1.9.2p290 :007 > report.document.records.with_address.last  
<Record _id: 4f593f245af0501074000122, _type: nil,  version: 1, name: "principal contact 3", title: "", dob: nil, address: "", email: "", phone: "", fax: "">
```

I can't figure out if I'm doing a query wrong, if this is a bug with Mongoid, or if there is some other issue. Does anyone have experience with such a query?

Comment: Shouldn't the query be using `$and` instead of `$or`?

Comment: no, that would never match ??  if the value is nil, it won't match "", and vice versa.

Comment: I agree, your or doesn't make sense. It's boolean logic, a!=1 or a!=2 will always return true, because it will always be not 1 or not 2.

Comment: agh! i knew i was probably getting lost in the logic of or and negative matching! thanks.

Comment: Agree with @Dieseltime, except, don't use $and, since that's the default when you filter on multiple criteria. $and actually makes it slower in some cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the end, this is the only way i could find that works to select records where a certain field is not nil and not blank:

```
scope :with_name, all_of(:name.ne => nil).all_of(:name.ne => "")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going to chuckle at this.

Neither nil nor "" is the same as saying:
Not nil and not "".

You really mean `and`, and that can be expressed without `$and`, using just:

```
$ne=>nil, $ne=>""
```

Comment: Are you referring to mongoid syntax here, or mongo?  Trying to extrapolate from your suggestion, I have tried both of these in mongoid: where(:name.ne => nil, :name.ne => ""), where(:address => {"$ne" => "", "$ne" => nil }).  in both cases, mongoid appears to be collapsing the criteria, so that the former ends up as {:name=>{"$ne"=>""}} for the selector, and the latter ends up as {:address=>{"$ne"=>nil}}

Comment: Sorry, yeah the mongo syntax would be:
{address:{$ne:null}, address:{$ne:""}}

Comment: Looks like excludes is the proper way to do it in mongoid? Model.excludes(address: nil, address: "") -- or maybe not, since it's an embedded doc...

Comment: excludes actually has the same behavior:  excludes(name: nil, name: "") becomes selector: {:name=>{"$ne"=>""}}

Answer (score 0):

You can do the more succint:

```
scope :with_name, where(:name.nin => ["", nil])
```

See [MongoDB manual](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/).