# Mongoid "where" query for nil or ""

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I need to query my mongodb collection for anything that has a foreman equal to nil or ""

this is what I have so far... but I dont know how to alter it to accept `nil` and `""`, I found this, but its SUPER not clear and I havent been able to make it work

[OR query matching nil or "" with Mongoid still matches ""?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641924/or-query-matching-nil-or-with-mongoid-still-matches)

```
where(foreman: '', status: 'Active').order_by(first_name: :asc)
```

Answer (score 0):

solved, the answer was using `any_of` instead of `where`

```
any_of({foreman: nil, status: 'Active'}, {foreman: '', status: 'Active'}).order_by(first_name: :asc)
```

more info was found here:
[Mongoid OR query syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999368/mongoid-or-query-syntax)